# Conditional expectation of $\cos (2\pi X)$ on $\sin (2\pi X)$? Are they mean independent?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable that follows uniform distribution in $[0,1]$.

what is the expectation of $\cos (2\pi X)$ conditional on $\sin (2\pi X)$?

What I have thought about is this is not as simple as given $X$, since $\sin (2\pi X)$ is periodic. Given $\sin (2\pi X)$ equals some value actually gives a sequence of plausible values for $X$.

Comment: Not sure why people downvote this question, but this one is not that trivial I believe.

Comment: It is downvoted because the notation is unclear and not typesetted, and because you haven’t provided any of your own work/explorations in answering your problem.

Comment: @heepo thanks for the comment. I am new here and still learning. Will try my best to improve.

Comment: Why do you say for $\sin X = y$ you have a set of possibile values for $X$? The range of $X$ allows at most *one* value, does it not?

Comment: @user10158324 I don’t have the link on me (using mobile) but there should be some helpful forums on using the built in Latex typesetting tool in MSE. You can also inspect others’ posts to see how they use it.

Comment: @dfnu you are right. Then I guess I'm looking for more general cases. Like conditional expectation of $\cos(2\pi X)$ on $\sin(2\pi X)$. In this case there should be more than 1 value of plausible X?

Comment: @user10158324 in that case I'd say yes, you'd have at most two (opposite) possible values for $\cos X$.

Comment: @heepo thanks! I just tried using latex codes on mobile and it seems to work.

Comment: You might be interested in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817788/conditioning-a-random-variable-x-by-a-function-of-x-the-continuous-case, although the results in that question seem stronger than what you need here.

Comment: @dfnu I'm not sure why the two values are opposite? I'm thinking a horizontal line that intersect sin function.

Comment: @user10158324 Just use the definition of sine and cosine on the circumference or radius $1$ centered in the origin of the axes.

Comment: @dfnu I see! This is a very straightforward

Comment: @Riley thanks for the link. I will try to figure that out. It seems a bit beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cos(2\pi X) = \text{sign}(\cos(2\pi X))|\cos(2\pi X)| = \text{sign}(\cos(2\pi X)) \sqrt{1-\sin^2(2\pi X)}$, we have $$E(\cos(2\pi X)|\sin(2\pi X)) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2(2\pi X)} E[\text{sign}(\cos(2\pi X))|\sin(2\pi X)]$$

Note that $E[\text{sign}(\cos(2\pi X))|\sin(2\pi X)] = E[1_{\cos(2\pi X)>0}|\sin(2\pi X)]- E[1_{\cos(2\pi X)\leq 0}|\sin(2\pi X)]$ and for reasons of symmetry we have $E[1_{\cos(2\pi X)>0}|\sin(2\pi X)]= E[1_{\cos(2\pi X)\leq 0}|\sin(2\pi X)]$. Thus 
$$E(\cos(2\pi X)|\sin(2\pi X)) = 0$$

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for formalizing the idea of symmetry!